# Jordan canonical bases and form

Tags: matrices

Find the Jordan bases and the Jordan canonical form for the following matrices:

$\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 3 \\
\\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$ (sorry about the formatting)

So I found the eigenvalues $\lambda=2,2$ and then I have to find an eigenvector I think:

$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 3 \\
\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
\\
y 
\end{pmatrix}$=$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

So I get the equation $0x+3y=0$ so x is a free variable and $y=0$. So my book tells me the eigenvector $v_1\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
\\
0 
\end{pmatrix}$ but I ma having a little trouble understanding where the 1 comes from.

i need to find another vector $v_2 $ and how we did this in class is we solved for x in terms of y but I can't do that in this case I think because x is multiplied by 0.  My book gives $v_2=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
\\
1/3
\end{pmatrix}$ but I don't see how they got that.

So then $J=M^-1AM$

where $M=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
\\
0 & 1/3
\end{pmatrix}$

$A=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 3 \\
\\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$

and $M^-1=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
\\
0 & 3
\end{pmatrix}$

so $J=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
\\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$

Which is of the right form. I just don't understand some of the intermediate steps, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $\ker(A-2I)\varsubsetneq \ker(A-2I)^2=\mathbf R^2$ (by Hamilton-Cayley), hence what you have to do is finding a vector $v_2$ such that $(A-2I)v_2=v_1$. You'll find $v_2$ as in your book, an at the same time,  you have both $Av_1=2v_1$  and $Av_2=2v_2+v_1$, whence the Jordan normal form.

Answer (score 1):

the matrix $A=\pmatrix{2&3\\0&2}$ is almost in jordan form. if you want the canonical form $J=\pmatrix{2&1\\0&2}$  change the basis $\{e_1=(1,0)^\top, e_2 = (0,1)^\top\}$ to the basis $\{3e_1, e_2\}.$

$\bf edit:$ the transformation $T$ that is represented by $A$ with respect to the standard basis $\{e_1, e_2\}.$  that is $$Te_1 = 2e_1, Te_2 = 3e_1+2e_2$$ suppose we want to choose a basis $\{f_1=ae_1+ce_2, f_2=be_1+de_2\}$ so that $$Tf_1 = 2f_1, Tf_2 = f_1 + 2f_2 $$ we have the following equations for the constants:

$$2ae_1 + c(3e_1+2e_2)=2ae_1+2ce_2 \to c = 0\\
2be_1+d(3e_1+2e_2)=ae_1+2(be_1+de_2) $$

one choice is $$a = 3, b = 0, c = 0, d = 1$$

Comment: Hm..I see that it's almost in Jordan canonical form but I don't understand your explanation exact;y

Comment: @MathMajor Abel is showing you wrt which basis is your matrix in JCF ...